Tag for "time between blocks": Block-Interval or Block-Solution-Time?
We seem to have several tags that collect questions on the same topic (and a lot of the questions about it aren't properly tagged at all).
The questions concerned with the time between blocks seem to be tagged inconsistently with the tags block-interval, block-solution-time, speed, difficulty, and confirmations.
difficulty and confirmations have a different focus for me, speed is completely unfocussed and should be removed altogether.
Which one should we use then: block-interval, block-solution-time or something else entirely?


difficulty and confirmations have a different focus for me, speed is completely unfocussed and should be removed altogether.

I agree.

Which one should we use then: block-interval, block-solution-time or something else entirely?

block-interval. block-solution-time implies that we can predict how long an individual block will take to solve, which isn't true.

I liked the argument, so I went right ahead and merged [tag:block-solution-time] into [tag:block-interval].
